# How do i Import an npm Module in vue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, electron

Basically i want to implement discord rpc in my electron browser apllication and i found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-rich-presence) npm module for it.

I Noticed i can't import it using the default node.js way, my application just ignores it that way

```
const client = require('discord-rich-presence')('180984871685062656');
```

I Will need to import it using import (as far as i know)

```
import client from 'discord-rich-presence';
```

now my question is, how do i implement that argument in the second bracket

Comment: According to this module description: In browser you can import/require it as discord-rich-presence/browser. However, it should be noted that currently using rich presence in browser is a feature whitelisted by Discord, and you will most likely be unable to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are importing a funcion and calling it in the same line.
In ES6 you can do the same in with these two lines: first import the function, then call it.

```js
import discordRichPresence from 'discord-rich-presence';
const client = discordRichPresence('180984871685062656');
```